# Show that if a matrix $A$ of order $3×3$ satisfies $A^3=O$, then $I^3−A$ is invertible and its inverse is equal to $I^3+A+A^2.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

I need to show that if $A^3=0$, then $I^3−A$ is invertible and its inverse is equal to $I^3+A+A^2$. I have been at this question for almost an hour and do not know how to approach it, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Literally all you need to do is show that $(I_3 - A)(I_3 + A + A^2) = I_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Compute $(I^3-A)(I^3+A+A^2)$, from there, you are able to answer the two questions.

Comment: Doing this I arrive at  $I^2+A^2I-A^2-A^3$, where do I go from here?

Comment: your expression can be simplify to $I+A^2-A^2-O$ right, further simplify it and see what you get and think from the definition of inverse.

Comment: Sorry, this is a dumb question, but how did you get to $I+A^2-A^2-O$ from my expression? I know that $A^3$ is just $0$, but how did you simplify the rest?

Comment: $I$ is the identity matrix, hence $A^2I = A^2$ and also $I^3=I$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply $I-A$ and $I+A+A^2$.